# How to provide numberings to the radio-buttons in android?

Tags: android, android-view

I have a RadioGroup in which, I have provided four different radio button with text as :

```
<RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radio_group"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:background="@color/textbackgroundcolor"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_one"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textStyle="bold" 
                    android:textSize="12dp"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_two"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textStyle="bold" 
                    android:textSize="12dp"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_three"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textStyle="bold" 
                    android:textSize="12dp"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_four"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textStyle="bold" 
                    android:textSize="12dp"/>
            </RadioGroup>
```

As of now, it display radio buttons with their text. But I want to display some labels/numbers before each radio button.

How can I provide numbers like 1, 2, 3, 4 for radio button?

Comment: You can also extend Radiobutton class and implement your own layout and function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different ways to do this. But the easiest way that comes to mind is just to add a `TextView` before each and place it in a `LinearLayout` together with each `RadioButten`

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radio_group"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:background="@color/textbackgroundcolor"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" >

           <LinearLayout >
                <TextView
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:minLines="2"
                     android:gravity="center"
                     android:textSize="15dp"
                     android:text="1"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_one"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:textStyle="bold" 
                    android:textSize="12dp"/>
           </LinearLayout>
</RadioGroup>
```

This is the general idea